# Chrome Remote Debugging - "Connection Lost" on Lollipop and Marshmallow

Tags: android

I'm using Chrome Remote Debugging to debug the WebView in my Android app.
This works fine for me when I run my app on a KITKAT device, and I can inspect all WebView elements (HTML, Javascript, ect.).
But I get a "Connection Lost" message when running my app on Lollipop and Marshmallow.
My Googling failed to find the antidote. Any clue will be HIGHLY appreciated. 
I didn't figure out which part of the code to post here, since the question deals with infrastructure.
Many Thanks in advance!

Comment: IS there any security apps installed on the devices ? anti-virus or similar , that might kill the connection?

Comment: I checked. None (at least none that I installed explicitly). Your comment triggered me to check security settings. Anything specific to check there?

Comment: Did you make sure you are using the static method WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true) ?

Comment: Yes Thanks. Here it is:  `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) 
  WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);`

Comment: What device do you need? http://www.ironlab.io allows debugging on real devices in the cloud. They are in free beta now.